# Field "" in "" required a bean of type "" that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, sts

I'm struggling through a Spring Web API tutorial, using STS4.

I got to the state in the tutorial where I need to test it, but I just got a "not found", so the routing doesn't seem to be working.

I saw online comments that seem to suggest I need a `@ComponentScan("com.example")` adding to the `main()` function, something not mentioned in the tutorial.

So I did this but now I'm getting the following.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field pollRepository in com.example.controller.PollController required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.PollRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @javax.inject.Inject()


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.repository.PollRepository' in your configuration.
```

My project looks like this:

[image]

The `main` method (in `QuickPollApplication.java`):

```
package com.example.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan("com.example")
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuickPollApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuickPollApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and `PollController.java` looks like this:

```
package com.example.controller;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.domain.Poll;
import com.example.repository.PollRepository;

@RestController
public class PollController {

    @Inject
    private PollRepository pollRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/polls")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Poll>> getAllPolls() {
        Iterable<Poll> allPolls = pollRepository.findAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allPolls, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and this is `PollRepository.java`:

```
package com.example.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.example.domain.Poll;


public interface PollRepository extends CrudRepository<Poll, Long> {

}
```

Let me know if it would be helpful to show anything else!

As per a suggestion I tried adding `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example")` to the QuickPollApplication class, but this just resulted in more errors, starting with:

> Error creating bean with name 'pollController': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'pollRepository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'pollRepository' defined in
> com.example.repository.PollRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on QuickPollApplication: Invocation of
> init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
> com.example.domain.Poll

Comment: I'm coming from the Spring Boot Context so I'm not sure, but you would need to anotate `PollRepository` with `@Repository` there. Is there an pendant for that in Spring?

Comment: Didn't fix the issue, but good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you move application main class to `com.example` package instead?

If not,
You can try adding
`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example")` to QuickPollApplication class.

Also you require additional config like @EntityScan with base packages configured.

**Explaination:**

By default, Spring Boot enables JPA repository support and looks in the package (and its subpackages) where @SpringBootApplication is located. If your configuration has JPA repository interface definitions located in a package that is not visible, you can point out alternate packages by using @EnableJpaRepositories and its type-safe basePackageClasses=MyRepository.class parameter.

**Ref:**
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got more errors, starting with `Error creating bean with name 'pollController'` (added to question).

Comment: keep component scan as is do not remove it

Comment: Yes I didn't remove that.

Comment: Can you try moving QuickPollApplication to com.example package?
Also ensure Poll class is Entity

Comment: That worked! Awesome. Thanks so much :) If you update your answer I'll accept it