# How Do I Solve The Error "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name"

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have been writing a test case for my Dashboard Repository Class. When I try to run my Test Case I get the following error.

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.unicorn.dashboard.repository.DashboardRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 76 more
```

Given below is my Dashboard Repository which extends Mongo Repository

```
public interface DashboardRepository extends MongoRepository<Dashboard, String> {
    List<Dashboard> findByOrganizationIdAndActive(String organizationEncryptedId, boolean active);
}
```

Given below is my test class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.unicorn.dashboard.model"})
@DataJpaTest(properties = {"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
class DashboardRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired()
    DashboardRepository dashboardRepository;

    /**
     * Method under test: {@link DashboardRepository#findByOrganizationIdAndActive(String, boolean)}
     */
    @Test
    @Disabled("TODO: Complete this test")
    void testFindByOrganizationIdAndActive() {
        // TODO: Complete this test.
        //   Reason: R027 Missing beans when creating Spring context.
        //   Failed to create Spring context due to missing beans
        //   in the current Spring profile:
        //       com.unicorn.dashboard.repository.DashboardRepository
        //   See https://diff.blue/R027 to resolve this issue.

        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        dashboard.setActive(true);
        dashboard.setCollectionId("42");
        dashboard.setCreatedBy(1L);
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        dashboard.setCreatedDate(Date.from(LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).atStartOfDay().atZone(zone).toInstant()));
        dashboard.setCreatedType(CreatedType.CUSTOMIZE);
        dashboard.setDescription("The characteristics of someone or something");
        dashboard.setId("42");
        ZoneId zone1 = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        dashboard.setLastModifiedDate(Date.from(LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).atStartOfDay().atZone(zone1).toInstant()));
        dashboard.setModifiedBy(1L);
        dashboard.setName("Name");
        dashboard.setOrganizationId("42");
        dashboard.setPlatformIds(new ArrayList<>());
        dashboard.setStatus(DashboardStatus.CREATED);
        dashboardRepository.save(dashboard);

        Dashboard dashboard1 = new Dashboard();
        dashboard1.setActive(true);
        dashboard1.setCollectionId("42");
        dashboard1.setCreatedBy(1L);
        ZoneId zone2 = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        dashboard1.setCreatedDate(Date.from(LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).atStartOfDay().atZone(zone2).toInstant()));
        dashboard1.setCreatedType(CreatedType.CUSTOMIZE);
        dashboard1.setDescription("The characteristics of someone or something");
        dashboard1.setId("42");
        ZoneId zone3 = ZoneId.of("UTC");
        dashboard1.setLastModifiedDate(Date.from(LocalDate.of(1970, 1, 1).atStartOfDay().atZone(zone3).toInstant()));
        dashboard1.setModifiedBy(1L);
        dashboard1.setName("Name");
        dashboard1.setOrganizationId("42");
        dashboard1.setPlatformIds(new ArrayList<>());
        dashboard1.setStatus(DashboardStatus.CREATED);
        dashboardRepository.save(dashboard1);

        List<Dashboard> dashboardList = new ArrayList<>();
        dashboardList.add(dashboard);
        dashboardList.add(dashboard1);

        assertThat(dashboardRepository.findByOrganizationIdAndActive("42",true)).isEqualTo(dashboardList);
    }
}
```

Given below is the list of files I have

[image: Files And Packages]

This is what my CoreApplication Class looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(value="com.unicorn")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.unicorn")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.unicorn")
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class CoreApplication {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        return modelMapper;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Please tell me how I could resolve this. I have gone through many Tutorials and other similar questions to this on StackOver Flow but none of them helped. Plase shed some light on this

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/73951837/1811348

also is your springbootapplication main file in base package or somewhere else? If not then this is a issue, its not able to find repository in packages you specified.

Comment: Hey @swapyonubuntu I have updated my question with all the files I have. Looks like my main file is in Base Package

Comment: Hey @swapyonubuntu. I have also included what's in my Core Application. I followed your instructions as given in the link but didn't find any success

Comment: from the image it seems your coreApplication is inside `com.unicorn.dashboard` package,
can you check again?

Comment: I have added a new image. It looked like as if it's inside com.unicorn.dashboard because the Dashboard package was expanded. I have now inserted a new image where the Dashboard folder is collapsed. So now you can see that the CoreApplication is inside com.uincorn @swapyonubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `@SpringBootApplication` annotation to CoreApplication class?

I feel then it should work.

Comment: I have updated the Code with @SpringBootApplication but it still did not solve my issue. Is it because I'm conducting my TestCases in a different package? I'm conducting my Test in DashboardRepository, to which the code is given above

Comment: Isn't there any solution for this?